# Assigning value to list elements in for loop, list names depending on loop

Tags: r, for-loop, names

I have the following problem. I am working with two for loops (running over i and j) and use the assign function to create lists whose names depend on i and j. Now, in another for loop withing the two loops, i want to fill my created lists with rasters, namely 19 rasters. However, I am failing to call my lists as they depend on i and j, thus, I am not able to fill them.

At the end, I would like to have 25 lists carrying the names rasterList_10N_010E, rasterList_20N_010E,... that each have 19 entries with the respective rasters.

Below you find my code. I have dropped lines not important for my problem (I actually generate the rasters I want to store in my lists depending on i and j within the loops, too).

```
for(i in 1:5){
for(j in 1:5){
nam <- paste0("rasterList_", i*10, "N_0", j*10, "E") 
assign(nam, list())    

  for (k in 1:19){
     raster_test <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)
    #here the list with the name nam should be standing
    rasterList_10N_010E[[k]] <- raster_test
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried solutions using

```
eval(as.name(nam))[[k]] <- raster_test
```

and

```
as.name(nam)[[k]] <- raster_test
```

but it did not work. I believe that the problem may be that the approach is not very R-like (I have just recently changed from Stata to R)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please forget that you’ve ever heard about the functions `assign` and `eval`. They are completely inadequate to solve such issues and make the the code vastly more complex for no gain.  Use named lists instead. (This type of questions is incredibly common here, and the use of `assign` and `eval` in this context is *never* the right answer; these functions are intended for very different purposes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating 25 single lists I would suggest to put your lists into one list like so:

Note: I have set `k = 2` for simplicity.

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

rasterList <- list()

for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
    name <- paste0(i * 10, "N_0", j * 10, "E")
    rasterList[[name]] <- list()
    for (k in 1:2) {
      raster_test <- raster(ncol = 36, nrow = 18, xmn = -1000, xmx = 1000, ymn = -100, ymx = 900)
      rasterList[[name]][k] <- raster_test
    }
  }
}

length(rasterList)
#> [1] 25

rasterList[["10N_010E"]]
#> [[1]]
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 18, 36, 648  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 55.55556, 55.55556  (x, y)
#> extent     : -1000, 1000, -100, 900  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 18, 36, 648  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 55.55556, 55.55556  (x, y)
#> extent     : -1000, 1000, -100, 900  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA
```

And if still necessary you could get your 25 lists afterwards like so:

```
lapply(names(rasterList), function(x) assign(paste0("rasterList_", x), rasterList[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>